# I am trying retrieving data from more than one table using joins in SQL Developer but I get an error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, alias, where-clause

```
select 
    e.first_name, e.last_name, 
    e.first_name || e.last_name "Name",
    d.department_name, d.manager_id,
    l.country_id, l.city
from 
    employees e
join 
    departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
join 
    locations l on d.location_id = l.location_id
where 
    d.manager_id = &d.manager_id;
```

Comment: What's with the `e.first_name || e.last_name "Name"`are you trying to concatenate the fields or use a logical `OR` operator?

Comment: The `&d` is a substitution variable so you should be prompted for a value - what do you supply? The `.` terminates the substitution. If you `set verify on` and run as a script you'll see how the substitution affects the final statement which should make clearer what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check if it help you ;)

```
select 
e.first_name, e.last_name, 
concat(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) "Name",
d.department_name, d.manager_id,
l.country_id, l.city
from 
employees e
join 
departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
join 
locations l on d.location_id = l.location_id
where 
d.manager_id = &d.manager_id;
```

Comment: Oracle's [concat function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CONCAT.html#GUID-D8723EA5-C93A-45C3-83FB-1F3D2A4CEAF2) only takes two arguments. Using `||` is fine, and doesn't explain the error.